# JavaScript Callback not called from button click

Tags: javascript, callback

Hello kind and patient people of the internet.

Note that I have read and re-read most all the Stackoverflow write ups on callbacks, went out to Safari Books online looking for an example of a simple callbacks that would make sense, and knocked my head against this callback stuff for awhile, but alas: just can't seem to get it...I'm trying to get a simple call back example working...something very simple that I can get my head around.

Here's the goal: click a button...have the button call a function that pops an alert, then after that, the callback pops an alert.

Here's some my sample code, that at least doesn't seem to throw any obvious syntax errors, but dang, darn, heck: doesn't work.

```
document.getElementById('test-callback-button').onclick = testMyCallBack;

function testMyCallBack() {
   runClientRequest3("ham", function() { alert("Thanks for the sandwich") });
}

function runClientRequest3(request, callback) {
     alert("My sandwich is: " + request);
     callback;
}
```

The alert "My sandwich is ham" pops up...but not the callback alert :-(
...just what am I (obviously) missing and not understanding?

thanks mucho in advanceo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 callback;
```

should be

```
 callback();
```